# Install local jar in plugin

Tags: maven, grails

I have a grails application and a grails plugin that I inject and use with this application. I have developed both and they are on 2.5.3.
I have a jar that I want to install in the plugin so I can use it in the application. 
I added it to the lib folder of the plugin, I can use it directly in the plugin but I cannot use it in my main application. I do not see the classes available in the local jar. I tried with the BuildConfig of the plugin in the plugins section but I still cannot see it in my main application. Please let me know if you understand my problem and I could rephrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One recommendation is to install the jar into local maven repo, as I assume this is a custom jar.

Instructions here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

If you have access to a full http maven repo then I recommend publishing it there.

Then reference that jar in `BuildConfig`.  The jar will be pulled out of the maven repo, and will be packaged with the application.